# How can i fix this undefined output text in javascript function

Tags: javascript

I make a simple calculator using javascript. I am providing those code below. But the problem is when i run those code. i saw a undefined output. I dont know why that text is showing. I want to remove that.

```js
function addition(x, y) {
  var sum = x + y;
  document.write("Addition of two number is : " + sum);
}

function substract(x, y) {
  var sub = x - y;
  document.write("Subtraction of two number is : " + sub);
}

function multiply(x, y) {
  var multiply = x * y;
  document.write("Multipication of two number is : " + multiply);
}

function division(x, y) {
  var division = x / y;
  document.write("Division of two number is : " + division);
}

var x = parseInt(prompt("Enter the first number : "));
var y = parseInt(prompt("Enter the second number : "));

var operator = prompt("Enter the operator : ");

if (operator == "+") {
  document.write(addition(x, y));
} else if (operator == "-") {
  document.write(substract(x, y));
} else if (operator == "*") {
  document.write(multiply(x, y));
} else if (operator == "/") {
  document.write(division(x, y));
} else {
  document.write("Invalid Operator. Please choose operator between +,-,* or /. <br> Thanks for using our calculator. ");
}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: @Andy just because question has the same keywords "why" and "undefined" doesn't make it a common question. The proposed answered question is not helpful here.

Comment: @vanowm, but the question got solved ages ago. Functions return `undefined` if they don't return anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `document.write(x)` causes `x` to be written.  If `x` is a function call, it will write whatever that function call returns.  Since all of your functions don't explicitly return something, they return (here it comes) `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

Your operator functions don't return anything, they write directly to the page.
However the lines that execute these functions write to the page the return of these functions, which is `undefined`

So to solve this, you have 2 options:

1. replace `document.write("blah")` with `return "blah"` in operator functions
2. remove `document.write()` from the caller: `document.write(addition(x, y))`